# An unexpected error has occurred when trying to save HTML code in script editor

Tags: web-part

I'm a beginner at this, I hope someone can help me..

I am modifying a demo web site in sharepoint 2013 that is published with dynamic AX R3 (Contoso), basically I have a full working web site.
[image: The demo website]

Lets imagine that I want a html button in this example just to make it work and later be able to write relevant code for my project.

When I try to use the web-part script editor to add a HTML button: [image: The button "Hello"]

...but when I press "save" in the sharepoint ribbon, this happens: 
[image: Wrong message] And the button won't be saved. I should mention that I have added other web-parts to the demo site, but when I want to add HTML or JavaScript in a script editor or in a content editor, it doesn't want to work.

So I googled and found out I could find the error message in the ULS logs and here it is:

> 04/29/2015 06:30:26.55    w3wp.exe (0x4054)   0x2B10  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException:
>   A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client
>   (a3564034-4a21-4e0d-bd49-6cf261a10384scriptcontent="").
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String
>   collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection
>   collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)     at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.GetParametersFromHttpRequest(SPSite
>   site, Boolean bAuthenticated)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite
>   site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean
>   bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken
>   appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout,
>   Boolean bAsAnonymous)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb
>   web)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext
>   context)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.GetContextWeb(HttpContext
>   context)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object
>   oSender, EventArgs ea)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)  be78019d-ccb5-90c5-d26a-0b8ce5adad13

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the HTML code you pasted inside the Script Editor?

Comment: check the web.config files of web app....https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c15773f1-abaa-4403-8103-cae5c2a808bc/a-potentially-dangerous-requestform-value-was-detected-from-the-client?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: @AmalHashim is was just <button></button>

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I have now tried exactly the solution in that thread but unfortunately it did't solve the problem for me. Any other tips? Thanks